# Issue with GRIB API, Jasper, Pygrib

Tags: python

During the recent days i had problem with GRIB API installation, i was able to install it with disable the --disable-shared flag but the problem is then i got an error while running Pygrib test "python animate.py" 
(GRIB_API ERROR   :  JPEG support not enabled.)

So i had to install the GRIB API again without disable the shared but i got this error:

```
Linking C shared library ../lib/libgrib_api.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libjasper.a(jpc_math.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libjasper.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libgrib_api.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/grib_api.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

then i started to compile Jasper again with -fPIC flag but i still got the 
"recompile with -fPIC" for that i changed the flags in MAKE file as:

```
CFLAGS = -fPIC
CPP = gcc -E
CPPFLAGS = 
CXX = g++
CXXCPP = g++ -E
CXXDEPMODE = depmode=gcc3
CXXFLAGS = -fPIC
FFLAGS = -fPIC
```

still no resualt ... i searched many but no resualt

Thanks in advance